# Embed framework into another framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

Im trying to create a `framework` which contains inside another `framework` and uses it internally only. I have tried various methods found on the internet, and now I have generated a `.framework` file which inside contains a folder called `Frameworks`, and there is this dependent `framework`. But when I try to use this, Im getting app crashes with

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x10090e390 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x10090e394 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x10090e398 <+8>:  b.lo   0x10090e3b0               ; <+32>
    0x10090e39c <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x10090e3a0 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x10090e3a4 <+20>: bl     0x10090d7d0               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x10090e3a8 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x10090e3ac <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x10090e3b0 <+32>: ret
```

I have added this dependency framework inside my framework target and added it to `Copy Files` phase. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

See this example :- [how-to-import-one-project-to-another-one-in-xcode](http://tuchangwei.github.io/2013/09/16/how-to-import-one-project-to-another-one-in-xcode/)

Due to user needs, I have to import one project to another one as a sub-project. The final result should be like the following picture.

It is not easy to do this. We need some steps.

**Step 1**, Add “project.xcodeproj” file to project, note that don’t choose the “Copy items into…”.

**Step 2**, close the project, because you have opened the project in project. If you don’t, you can just see the “project.xcodeproj” file and there is no triangle front of it, you will can’t expand it.

**Step 3**, generate static library. Choose “project.xcodeproj”,add Target. After generating static library, add swift file framework files to it.

**Step 4**, generate Bundle, and change the relevant settings to iOS target.